# Redirect every path with / to index.html using grunt

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

Hi I am building an angularjs application. I have removed hash form url but is cause one problem. When I am refreshing page other than home page it says

"Cannot GET /abculr/xyz"

I have used below given for removing hash

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
     requireBase: false
    });
```

While googling I know that `middleware` will do this form me. I have written code which is print `console` but I how to write direct code into it.

```
middleware:function(){
            console.log('hiiiiii')
          }
```

Grunt file

```
// Generated on 2015-11-04 using
// generator-webapp 1.1.0
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// If you want to recursively match all subfolders, use:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Automatically load required grunt tasks
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
    useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin'
  });

  // Configurable paths
  var config = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    config: config,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      babel: {
        files: ['<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['babel:dist']
      },
      babelTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['babel:test', 'test:watch']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'postcss']
      }
    },

    browserSync: {
      options: {
        notify: false,
        background: true,
        watchOptions: {
          ignored: ''
        }
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          files: [
            '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
            '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*',
            '.tmp/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
          ],
          port: 9000,
          server: {
            baseDir: ['.tmp', config.app],
            routes: {
              '/bower_components': './bower_components'
            }
          },
          middleware:function(){
            console.log('hiiiiii')
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          open: false,
          logLevel: 'silent',
          host: 'localhost',
          server: {
            baseDir: ['.tmp', './test', config.app],
            routes: {
              '/bower_components': './bower_components'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          background: false,
          server: '<%= config.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= config.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    eslint: {
      target: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
        '!<%= config.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
        'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
      ]
    },

    // Mocha testing framework configuration options
    mocha: {
      all: {
        options: {
          run: true,
          urls: ['http://<%= browserSync.test.options.host %>:<%= browserSync.test.options.port %>/index.html']
        }
      }
    },

    // Compiles ES6 with Babel
    babel: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/scripts',
          src: '{,*/}*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/scripts',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      },
      test: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'test/spec',
          src: '{,*/}*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/spec',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      }
    },

    postcss: {
      options: {
        map: true,
        processors: [
          // Add vendor prefixed styles
          require('autoprefixer')({
            browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions', 'Firefox ESR']
          })
        ]
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= config.app %>/index.html'],
        exclude: ['bootstrap.js'],
        ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)*\.\./
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= config.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.*',
          '<%= config.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
          '<%= config.dist %>/*.{ico,png}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      options: {
        dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
      },
      html: '<%= config.app %>/index.html'
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%= config.dist %>',
          '<%= config.dist %>/images',
          '<%= config.dist %>/styles'
        ]
      },
      html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true,
          // true would impact styles with attribute selectors
          removeRedundantAttributes: false,
          useShortDoctype: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.dist %>',
          src: '{,*/}*.html',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care
    // of minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not
    // wish to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= config.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
    //         '<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            'images/{,*/}*.webp',
            '{,*/}*.html',
            'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
          src: 'fonts/*',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'babel:dist',
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'babel',
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'babel',
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'start the server and preview your app', function (target) {

    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'browserSync:dist']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'postcss',
      'browserSync:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run([target ? ('serve:' + target) : 'serve']);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', function (target) {
    if (target !== 'watch') {
      grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:test',
        'postcss'
      ]);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'browserSync:test',
      'mocha'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'postcss',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy:dist',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:eslint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Comment: From NG-BOOK: "The back-end server will have to support URL rewriting on the server side. To support HTML5 mode,
the server will have to make sure to deliver the index.html page for all apps. That ensures that our
Angular app will handle the route."

Comment: Yes but I think grunt can serve this puroise. I am using node server'